# Why is symmetric group not matrix?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

I have just learned from mighty Wikipedia that the symmetric group of an infinite set is not a matrix group. Why?

I can see rep-theory reasons: sizes of minimal non-trivial, non-sign representations of $S_n$ grow as $n$ grows. But I believe that there should really be an elementary linear algebra argument for this. Is there one?

Comment: Assume that your infinite symmetric group $G$ has an $n$ dimensional representation over a field $k$. You will be certainly able to find infinitely many elements of $G$ of order two that commute with each other. If $char(k)\neq 2$ then you can simultaneously diagonalized the matrices corresponding to these elements of order two. But then you see that you have only 2^n-1 choices for them. Contradiction. Does it work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:**  My original idea doesn't work, but unknown's does.  Here are the details.

Let $k$ be a field, which is WLOG algebraically closed.  Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional representation over $k$ of dimension $n$.  Then $S_{\infty}$ contains $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}))^{p^n}$ (in fact any finite group) as a subgroup, where $p \neq \text{char}(k)$.  Let $g_1, ... g_{p^n}$ be its generators.  Then by "elementary linear algebra" $V$ is a direct sum of $1$-dimensional irreps of $\langle g_1 \rangle$ which $g_2, ... g_{p^n}$ must preserve, while still having order $p$.  But there are only $p^n - 1$ nontrivial ways to do this; hence either one of the $g_i$ acts as the identity or two of them are the same and $V$ cannot be faithful.

Of course, whether this is "elementary linear algebra" or representation theory is debatable, and I think irrelevant.  All I did was find a sequence of finite groups such that the dimension of the smallest faithful representation goes to infinity and I could have done this any number of ways, e.g. I could have chosen $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Comment: So can we agree that the main point is the following: If $S_\infty$ had a finite-dimensional faithful representation over some field $k$, then the dimension of minimal faithful representations of finite groups over $k$ was uniformly bounded, which is "clearly" wrong, and there are many ways to make that clearly really clear.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be really elementary, but ... We know that $M_n(k)$ satisfies polynomial identities. For instance, the Amitsur-Levitski Theorem tells us that
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_{2n}}\epsilon(\sigma)A_{\sigma(1)}\cdots A_{\sigma(2n)}=0_n,
\qquad\forall A_1,\ldots,A_{2n}\in M_n(k).$$
On the contrary, the symmetric group of an infinite set does not satisfy polynomial identities.

Comment: @Denis: What is a polynomial identity of a group? If you mean the usual identity (law), then your answer is wrong. The free group does not satisfy any  identity, but is inside $M_2(k)$. Perhaps you meant that $S_\infty$ does not embed into the multiplicative semigroup of any PI ring. That is true, but requires a proof which is certainly more complicated than the original question.

Comment: @Mark. Right. It is more involved than I thought initially.

Comment: @Denis Take $A=kS_\infty /I$ where $I$ is the ideal generated by the values of the standard polynomial. You are saying that $S_\infty \rightarrow kS_\infty /I$ is not injective. I am not sure how difficult it is to find $1-g$ in $I$.

Comment: @Mark Are there nonmatrix groups embeddable into PI-algebras at all?

Comment: @Bugs Bunny: Of course there are. For example, $({\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})^\infty$ embeds into a commutative ring (its group algebra). In the finitely generated case, though, the situation is different because of Braun's theorem that the radical of PI rings is nilpotent. 

Answer (score 1):

The symmetric group of an enumerable set contains every enumerable group as a subgroup. Its linearity would thus imply the linearity of every enumerable group which is false for example 
by the Tits's alternative.

Comment: Roland, the group I'm thinking of is the group of symmetries which fix all but finitely many elements.  This group is _way_ bigger, although it might be the group that is actually meant by the question.

Comment: His name is Tits, not Tit.

Comment: Considering the group of all permutations with compact support 
(fixing all but a finite number of elements), the above argument applies to all finite groups and implies the existence of an universal bound $M$ such that every finite group has a faithful representation of dimension at most $M$.

Comment: @Roland: Is there an elementary reason why that is false?